# In Windows 8 my mouse pad stops responding (for 1 second) to input after typing on the keyboard

Tags: windows-8

I've updated my Alienware m14x R1 to Windows 8. Something in the driver system\software is causing the mouse pad to stop responding when I use the keyboard. I assume this is to prevent accidental touching of the mouse with your hands.

Does anyone know what setting this is? I want to disable this or change the amount of time it is paused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the Properties window for the Synaptics Touch Pad settings, go to:
Pointing->Sensitivity->TouchCheck

The setting in this determines how long it disables the touchpad after using the keyboard. If set to the minimum, it will disable the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off SmartSense in the Synaptics settings

Comment: Do you know where this is? I cannot seem to find it. I have the Synaptics property window open and it has a bunch of categories. I've expanded them all but I cannot find it.

Comment: Some OEM drivers might have the option hidden and forced on - try the generic driver from Synaptics' own site.

Comment: I looked up SmartSense on Synaptics website and it seems that it's more of a code name for a bunch of features. The only way to turn it off is really just to disable the Synaptics driver itself. But as I posted above, I found the specific setting I was looking for. Thanks for helping though. :)